# Why is my Ruby on Rails link_to sending the action twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link_to method in my Ruby on Rails application in one of the views, and when I click on it, the controller is set to do a whole bunch of things... But for some reason I'm seeing this GET request twice even when I click on the link one time.

Here's what the link looks like:

```
    <%= link_to image_tag("excel.png"), spreadsheet_technical_report_path(report) %>
```

Which goes to /technical_report/id/spreadsheet and here's what it looks like in the controller:

```
  def spreadsheet
    spreadsheet = GenerateSpreadsheet.generate(params[:id])
    send_file spreadsheet
  end
```

I've even replaced the contents of that function with a binding.pry, and it hits it twice! This is so confusing. my whole GenerateSpreadsheet model does a variety of things and takes approximately a minute, and this second request does nothing but double that time.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here? I don't have a view set up for this since I want it to just send the user a download prompt (which it's doing) and not necessarily go to a view. I don't even know if not having a view is even relevant here.

Comment: Sometimes it happens due to js conflicts or js is loaded twice in application, please check that

Comment: I modified the app to load page-specific JS scripts and it's still doing it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Go to root folder of your application. Run this command `rm -r assets` and run your server in development mode. Tell me if it fixes that problem.

Comment: It seems that it's working now (by loading page specific JS scripts). Not sure why it didn't work the first time. Going to try Harry's suggestion if it starts up again. Thanks so much guys!

Comment: One small tip: Notify your controller that you want excel format and let the controller action respond accordingly: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

Comment: Sorry the command is `rm -r public/assets`

Comment: [`rake assets:clobber`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/README.md#usage) does the same :)

Answer (score 4):

**JS**

To add to the comments, the main issue here would likely be that you've bound some javascript to the page's `a` elements.

With an absence of `remote: true` and other hooks, the *only* thing which would likely cause a double-fire from your `link_to` is if Javascript is sending an ajax request too.

---

You mention that you...

> removed `//= require tree .` from my `application.js`

... whilst good that this fixed the issue, you have to remember that nothing happens with computers without them being told to do it. IE your "link" wouldn't just double-click for the sake of it.

If your JS works when you remove the `//require_tree .`, you'll want to look at the other JS files you have. There will be one where you're binding to the `$("a").on("click"` event, which is likely leading to the double-firing of your link.

Comment: Any idea why I don't have any "js" files loaded at all but yet it's still submitting two requests? The first request now is just a GET, the next one is a HEAD... This is so annoying.

Comment: Can you post the console screenshot? I would also like to know what this issue is

Comment: Here it is. This is the result from having an empty application.js file: http://imgur.com/a/XW9rC

Comment: After I added a view for the spreadsheet action, all of the errors in the second screenshot go away but the HEAD request still comes through and it's annoying. Should I modify the action in the controller to only perform the spreadsheet stuff if the request is a GET request and not a HEAD request perhaps?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by HEAD request? Maybe I'm being stupid, but I just can't see it from your screenshot

Comment: Check out second image in that imgur link (the one with the long output). Right above where my "binding.pry" starts at the bottom of that screenshot, it's a HEAD "/technical_reports" etc. The first screenshot is a GET request and the second one is a HEAD request. Both are causing the controller to do the same action twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to chaitanya saraf's comment, I just removed the "//= require tree ." from my application.js to get this fixed. Once I got rid of this, I added this to my config/initializers/asset.rb file

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [/.*\.js/,/.*\.css/]
```

Got rid of this annoying problem nice and easily.