# link_to tag is being called with my project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="manage">
<h2>Managing Users</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Add User", users_new_path, method: :get, class: "btn btn-primary" %> <br />  <!--  To go add-user-page  --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn"> Emails</button><br /></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn"> Delete</button><br /></td>
    </tr>

    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><button class="btn btn-info"><%= user.email %></button></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Del", users_delete_path(id: user.id), method: :delete ,class: "btn btn-info", data: { confirm: "You sure?" }%></td>
      </tr>

    <% end %>

</table> 

</div>
```

In this file, delete action and new action are called twice.
I tried according to stack all answers(
[link_to :confirm displays popup twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475449/link-to-confirm-displays-popup-twice)
[Why is my Ruby on Rails link_to sending the action twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985935/why-is-my-ruby-on-rails-link-to-sending-the-action-twice). and etc)

Who can help me?

Edited - Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please clarify? What do you expect to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: <%= link_to "Del", users_delete_path(id: user.id), method: :delete ,class: "btn btn-info", data: { confirm: "You sure?" }%></td> is called twice. So an error rises when delete user from database.

Comment: That would suggest issues with the JavaScript loading / event binding. Please add the contents of your `application.js`. The controller action might be useful, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to remove `//require rails-ujs` line.

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Thank you! You are life saver!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have both `jquery_ujs` and `rails-ujs` in your `application.js`. As they both implement & automatically bind the `confirm` events, you're seeing two of them.  You will need to remove `rails-ujs` to resolve the issue.